# Setting up an iterated integral in spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I am instructed to convert this iterated integral in cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates.
$$
\int^{1}_{0} \int^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}_{\sqrt{3x^2+3y^2}}\, dzdydx
$$

This seems that the bounds of the region are between the equations $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$, $z^2=3x^2+3y^2$, and the y=axis. I think that the region is also bounded by the y-axis because of the lower bound of $x = 0$.

In spherical coordinates, I know that the $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ is equal to $\rho = 2$.
The $z^2=3x^2+3y^2$ will be transformed into
$$
\rho^2 \cos^2\phi = 3(\rho^2-\rho^2 \cos^2\phi)\implies \phi = \frac{\pi}{6}.
$$
At the latter, I conclude that the iterated integral will be
$$
\int^{\frac{\pi}{6}}_0 \int^\pi_0\int^2_0 \rho^2 \sin\phi\, d\rho d\theta d\phi.
$$

I got the conclusion about the bounds of $\theta$ because of the sphere.
Overall, the resulting iterated integral in cartesian coordinates and the spherical coordinates is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
I want to know now if my understanding about the conversion is correct. Is there a visual representation of this integral to fully understand on how triple integral in spherical coordinates works?

Comment: It is correct except that $\theta$ should be between $ - \pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ assuming you are going with $x = \rho \ cos\theta \sin \phi, y = \rho \sin\theta \sin \phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$.

Comment: Just FYI - in 3 dimensions, $x = 0$ is the $yz$-plane, not the $y$-axis.

Comment: This is the intersection of a solid upside-down circular cone with vertex at the origin and the $z$ axis as its axis of symmetry, and the sphere of radius $2$ centered at the origin. The resulting shape is similar to a snow cone. But then it is cut in half  by the $yz$-plane.